# How do I read cap files with python efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some .CAP files (not PCAP file)  from capturing packages with tcpdump.

When I try to open with wireshark, the machine gets very slow, as I imagine that it tries to load everything into RAM.

I do not need to read the whole file at once. Imagine that I want to read the .CAP file only from time (time) = 9:15 p.m. to 11:12 p.m. instead of loading all into memory.

How can I do it in Python?

This is a CAP file:

[CAP file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2U5t.png)

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is to filter the packets *before* it gets to Python. `tshark` is a tool that can help with this. I haven't tried this, but I think the `-r` option can be used to read the file and then a filter can be used to filter it.

Comment: CAP and PCAP are the same?

Comment: I'm referring to the files that can be viewed in Wireshark. That .cap file looks like a wireshark screenshot, so yeah, we're probably talking about the same filetype here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing scapy: pip install scapy

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("file.cap")
```